# android ImageView problems

Tags: android

I have this code, but I am having a problem. The app closed unfortunately, and I don't know what the problem is in this code.

My XML file consists of several ImageViews but I don't know why it closed... is it not possible to have many ImageViews?

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/c"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/d"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/e"/>

     <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/f"/>

      <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/g"/>     

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/h"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/i"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/j"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/k"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/l"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/m"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/n"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/o"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/p"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/q"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/r"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/s"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/t"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/u"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/v"/>

     <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/w"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/x"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/y"/>


</LinearLayout>


 </ScrollView>
```

**Here's the LogCat:**

```
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thesis.americansignlanguage/com.thesis.americansignlanguage.AlphabetTutorial}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.thesis.americansignlanguage.AlphabetTutorial.onCreate(AlphabetTutorial.java:12)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  ... 11 more
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  ... 25 more
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
03-12 11:37:55.481: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  ... 28 more
03-12 11:37:57.390: I/Process(879): Sending signal. PID: 879 SIG: 9
03-12 11:37:58.420: E/Trace(949): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: what is your 101 line on the xml file

Comment: May be your images are high resolution Images.

Comment: @LucianNovac what do you mean 101 line?

Answer (score 3):

This is an `outOfMemory` problem that is happening because your are loading too much images in your application that exceeds the memory that the `OS` assigned to your application.

This problem may not occurs if your are using a high performance device or you are scaling your images.

Try to use `Adapter` to draw your images and to put them into your UI dynamically. The `Adapter` only draws the images that you are viewing into your screen currently. But in your code you are trying to load all the images at the beginning.

Here is an [example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html) how to use `ListView` with adapter to display images

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with low quality images and it work fine. You should use custom Adapter class to load images dynamically. This [example](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) will help you to make it happen.

Comment: i dont know how to use adapter class. haha i haven't tried that yet

Comment: Then you should first go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)